# Firebase - Permission Denied Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to check the Firebase database for existing values, then I get permission denied. This primarily is triggered due to permissions on the database. Although I changed them, yet it doesn't seem to solve the issue. The structure I have is the following:

[image]

I have the following functions to check if the mobile number or username are taken when registering the user:

```
func usernameValidation(completion: (result: Bool) -> Void)
    {
        print("Inside usernameValidation")
        dbReference.child("usernamesTaken").queryOrderedByValue().queryEqualToValue(self.usernameTxtField.text!).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot!) -> Void in
            if(snapshot.childrenCount == 0 || snapshot == nil)
            {
                print("result is true in username validation")
                //Username Available
                completion(result:true)
            }else{
                print("result is false in username validation")
                //Username Taken
                completion(result:false)
            }
        })

    }

    func mobileValidation(completion: (result: Bool) -> Void)
    {

        dbReference.child("mobilesTaken").queryOrderedByValue().queryEqualToValue(self.mobileTxtField.text!).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot!) -> Void in
            if(snapshot.childrenCount == 0 || snapshot == nil)
            {
                //mobile Available
                completion(result:true)
            }else{
                //mobile Taken
                completion(result:false)
            }
        })

    }
```

And added the permissions in the database as following:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth == null",
    ".write": "auth == null",
      "usernamesTaken": {
      ".indexOn": ".value",
      ".read": "auth == null",
      ".write": "auth == null"
      },"mobilesTaken": {
      ".indexOn": ".value",
      ".read": "auth == null",
      ".write": "auth == null"
      }
  }
}
```

Yet whenever I execute the usernameValidation function above or mobileValidation function above, I get permission denied. What am I missing out? Is this something still to do with permissions?

Thanks,

Comment: Error message is self explanatory, It is PERMISSION DENIED.

Comment: I know that @ldindu and what I was asking what could still be leading to this knowing it was the permission denied error. I even shared the rules expecting some feedback

Comment: auth == null will only result true if it is null and is that what are you expecting, shouldn't you be checking against "auth != null"?

Comment: if auth!= null is added there, that means unless the user is authenticated, I wouldn't be able to conduct the check. since this is used in registration, the user is not authenticated.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue; I solved it by login-in a user to access the Firebase.